# Cannot find module with async component loading on react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have the following basic starting point to load a component [via import()](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting-import/).

```
function getComponentAsync(importPath: string) {
  return async (nextState, callback) => {
    const { default: Component } = await import(importPath);
    callback(null, Component);
  }
}

export default (
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute getComponent={getComponentAsync('app/components/Home')} />
  </Route>
);
```

The goal is to simply load a component at some path. However, I keep running into some errors:

[image: Errors in console]

I placed a debug statement to confirm that the import path was correctly passed down to the function. It appears to be.

[image: Debugger in chrome console shows correct values.]

However, I really can't find what it is trying to import nor why it is failing to import it... why would this be? I've also tried swapping out `import` for `require.ensure` and got the same results.